# determine whick button was clicked javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, button

I have a 10+ absolutely the same buttons on my page, I mean everything is the same - title, value etc.

How can I determine which button was clicked?

Comment: Do these buttons have different ID's or classes? Can you explain why this is needed more in your question?

Comment: Have a different **id** attribute for those buttons. Generate different ids if you are generating those buttons dynamically.

Comment: they have the same id and class

Comment: I mean I want the answer to be: Button nr 4 was clicked

Comment: They can't be *exactly* the same. Their `.position()` has to at least differ :)

Comment: That's a wrong pattern make id difference and class is same.

Answer (score 2):

The buttons must have different IDs, so you can determine which was clicked.

```
$('button').click(function(e){
    alert(e.target.id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can associate those buttons with unique IDs to determine which one is clicked, using the  event.target attribute.

Answer (score 0):

The DOM element will still be classed as unique regardless of the elements attributes.

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $(this).css('border','1px solid red');
});
```

Should highlight the clicked button.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you want to enumerate the buttons somehow. You can use [`.index` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/index/) to get the index of the clicked button among the selected ones:

```
var $buttons = $('.theButtons');

$buttons.click(function() {
    var index = $buttons.index(this);
});
```

`this` always refers to the element the event handler is bound to, i.e. always to the button that was clicked. You can do whatever you want with it.